# World Stock Markets that went up in 2008

Tags: equities, finance, historical-data, financial-markets, history

We all know that the US stock market(s) collapsed in price in 2008, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_bear_market_of_2007%E2%80%9309.

I was wondering what countries' stock markets went up throughout this period.

Include things like frontier markets and not just developed countries.

I cannot find a data source online.

Comment: Democratic People's Republic of Korea has not had a down year in stk market since 1948.

Comment: Slightly difficult to invest there though

Comment: There must be some markets that went up....

Comment: Most likely not. You could go to a library and check out The Economist magazine at end of 2008, they have a good table in each issue that recapitulates a large number of stock markets. I would be surprised if you can find a positive one that year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [stock market in Tunisia](https://www.quandl.com/data/TUNISSE/TUNINDEX-Tunis-Stock-Exchange-Index-TUNINDEX) seems to have gone up during 2008, however one would have to take into account about 5% of inflation.

Comment: Great! I wonder why this was

Comment: How did you find this particular one out of interest????